# Calculation of a numeric index for a Cartesian (two-dimensional) coordinate system

Tags: java, math, coordinates, coordinate-systems

Given a Cartesian (two-dimensional) coordinate system like the following:

[image: kartesian coordinate system]

Is it possible - and if, how - to calculate a unique, sortable index for each field? This means that, using the x and y coordinate, I want to calculate a index number ascending from left to right, top down. E.g.:

[image: unique numeric indexes]

(only) the following conditions must be met:

- Index numbers must be unique (even for larger systems)
- Numbers must be ascending (but not necessarily consecutive) from left to right and from top to bottom
- Must be full, positive Integer values
- Must be realizable in Java

**What I found out yet:** Addition, Multiplication and Power (e.g. x*y or x^y) doesn't work because different fields get the same index.

Method Body could look like the following:

```java
public Integer getIndex(Integer xCoordinate, Integer yCoordinate) {
  // ...
}
```

BTW: Coordinates are always positive (0 <= x < n)

Thanks for any advice.

### SOLUTION:

I solved the problem without calculating an index and used the simple comparable proposed by Teepeemm (see comments)

Comment: What do you mean by "Addition, Multiplication and Power doesn't work (collisions)"? The obvious answer used in your example is (#cols*row + col), but I'm assuming that would be covered by this statement.

Comment: Didn't get it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AndyTurner What i meant is, that e.g. x*y or x^y gives the same result for different fields. So I have to know the number of cols in the system to calculate the index?

Comment: @chris Trying to implement a Coordinate(Integer x, Integer y) object which implements java.lang.Comparable

Comment: @frank_neff do you actually require the unique index if all you're trying to do is implement Comparable?

Comment: We may as well assume (0,0) gets `0`.  The smallest that (n,0) could then be is `n-1`, and the smallest (0,1) could be is `n`.  Which is a long way of saying that you must know the number of columns if you want to do what you've asked.  But if you just want to implement `Comparable`, then say so in a new question (or just `return this.y==that.y?this.x-that.x:this.y-that.y`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious answer based upon your example is to use:

```
index = (#cols * row + col)
```

but this relies upon knowing the number of columns in advance, and that it is small enough that you don't get an overflow.

An alternative would be to index along diagonals:

```
index = ((row + col) * (row + col + 1))/2 + row
```

So your indexing looks something like:

```
  0   2   5   9
  1   4   8  13
  3   7  12  18
  6  11  17  24
```

---

By the way, because you're doing arithmetic, you are better using primitive `int` rather than boxed `Integer` to avoid creating unnecessary `Integer` objects (Effective Java 2nd ed Item 5).

Comment: So for the first solution, I have to know the number of columns (which I don't know there) and the second solution does not fit the required order (left to right / top-down). If I understand you right, it's not possible to achieve this only by knowing x and y?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your "required order" then - with the second solution, it increases going left to right; it increases going top to bottom; it increases going top-left to bottom-right. What else do you require?

Comment: If i use those index for e.g. a flat List, the order of fields (x/y) should be: (0/0) (0/1) (0/2) (0/3) (0/4) (1/0) (1/1) (1/2) etc. If i use your proposed (second) solution it will be (0/0) (1/0) (0/1) (2/0) (1/1) (0/2) etc. Or given a flat list using those indexes, if I split the first 4 entries, it should represent the the first line from left to right, the second 4 entries the second line and so on.

Comment: Which do you want: A unique indexing scheme or a way to implement `Comparable` such that it sorting the list by the natural order results in this output?

Comment: A Class Coordinate(int x, int y) implements Comparable which can be sorted in this order.

Comment: That is completely different to what you have written in your question. Please ask a new question which actually says what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29429517/3182664) actually contained everything that you need. According to your comments, you don't know the number of columns. In this case, you have to assume the worst: If you don't know whether there are less than 64k columns and less than 64k rows, then you don't even know whether there are enough `int`s to represent the different indices at all.

So one solution (that is "as generic as possible", given these unknowns) is to multiply the `y`-value not with the number of columns, but with the *maximum number of columns* for which an index can reasonably be computed. If you knew the maximum number of *rows*, then you could choose an appropriate number here, but if you don't, then you have to multiply by 65536 - which can be done as a left-shift by 16 bits. (Think about the sign bits here, if necessary).

The result could be

```
Shuffled: [(1,0), (2,1), (2,2), (0,2), (2,0), (1,1), (1,2), (0,0), (0,1)]
Sorted  : [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (0,2), (1,2), (2,2)]
Indices:
      0       1       2 
  65536   65537   65538 
 131072  131073  131074
```

Here is an example implementation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class AscendingIndices
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
        for (int x=0; x<3; x++)
        {
            for (int y=0; y<3; y++)
            {
                coordinates.add(new Coordinate(x,y));
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(coordinates);
        System.out.println("Shuffled: "+coordinates);        
        Collections.sort(coordinates);
        System.out.println("Sorted  : "+coordinates);

        System.out.println("Indices:");
        for (int y=0; y<3; y++)
        {
            for (int x=0; x<3; x++)
            {
                Coordinate c = new Coordinate(x,y);
                System.out.printf("%7d ", c.getIndex());
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }

   }
}

class Coordinate implements Comparable<Coordinate>
{
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    Coordinate(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    int getIndex()
    {
        return x + (y << 16);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "("+x+","+y+")";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Coordinate o)
    {
        return Integer.compare(getIndex(), o.getIndex());
    }

}
```